# How to get Blazor Checkbox Label to be clickable

Tags: checkbox, blazor, label, blazor-server-side

```
<div class="form-group">
    <InputCheckbox @bind-name="@claim.ID" @bind-id="@claim.ID" @bind-Value="@claim.Selected"></InputCheckbox>
    <label for="@claim.ID" class="pb-2">@claim.ToString()</label>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the label for the check box to be clickable.  Right now you have to touch or click the actual checkbox.

Comment: https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/GHOemWlS52zGVxWY59
It works just fine by clicking the label.

Comment: Well that is interesting.  It does not work on my box.  I am up to date and current on everything.

Comment: Now, I am wrapping the chk box in the label and it works properly.  Thank you very much.